# Get default Android Studio Theme

Tags: android-studio

I changed somehow my theme to this :

[image]

How can I restore to my lovely default darcula android studio theme?

After applying below suggestion it helped but still looks a little bit strange:

[image]

Comment: File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance > Theme dropdown box.

Comment: @AngelKoh your answer helped but it still looks a little bit strange, do you know how to repair it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > reset]

**Go through** : 
File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > (reset at top right)

This worked for me... Hope you will have your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

To install Custom theme in android studio --version 4.1.2

1. download theme file(.jar) from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/
2. open android studio
3. drag the .jar file into studio